# Tap event in sencha touch is prevented So how can i fire that event now?

Tags: mobile, extjs, click, touch, tap

Tap event in sencha touch is prevented So how can i fire that event now?

Comment: Prevented by what? By `preventDefault()`? [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a Tap event on a label, you can do this:

```
label.element.on({
    tap : function(e, t) { ... }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but my tap event is already prevented by default so i want to re-enable it......my problem is that i can't tab on button now.